# Vim: C++ back indent with #

Tags: vim, indentation

I use Vim in a C++ code with openmp sentences.

And in my `~/.vimrc`

```
 set ai " auto indent
```

my problem: when I use an openmp sentence (this begins with `#`) the cursor jumps to the beginning of the line without the auto indent.

Example:

```
int main()
{
  int idx = 100;
#pragma omp parallel private(idx) // jump to begin of line
```

, when I like this:

```
int main()
{
  int idx = 100;
  #pragma omp parallel private(idx) // This is OK
```

Can I set this in the autoindent in Vim?

Comment: How are you opening the newline on `int idx = 100;` or the line below ie o or O

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Vim puts a line in column 1 when it starts with `#` (preprocessor directives), if `cinkeys` contains `#`.
So you can remove `#` from `cinkeys` to disable this feature:

```
:set cinkeys-=0#
```